# Flip3D performance with two monitors

Tags: windows-7, performance, aero, multiple-monitors

Is there a way to improve performance of Flip3D using two monitors?

With a single monitor it feels a lot smoother.

Comment: As ChrisF says, without knowing any details of your system, specifically the graphics card, we cannot say why Flip3D is slow with 2 monitors and fine with only 1.  From experience though, I can say that Flip3D can be slow/sluggish with "onboard" graphics and works like a charm with a good "dedicated" graphics card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What graphics card do you have and how much memory does it have?

Flip 3D will require more memory and processing power than normal windows and when you double the area it has to operate across you are increasing those demands still further.

Also - while you might get good 3D performance when a windows is wholly contained on either monitor you *might* find a performance hit if it spans both. This is because the processing can't be done by one output path alone.

The ultimate solution might be that you have to buy a more powerful graphics card - or just live with the degraded performance.

Comment: Also, it's worth keeping in mind that non-primary monitors always have degraded 3D acceleration performance.  (Of course, Flip3D is lightweight enough that it isn't noticeable at all with sufficiently powerful hardware.)